# Python-Application .desktop-shortcut causing malfunction

Tags: python, linux, kde-plasma, shortcut-file

I wanted to create a desktop launcher for my Python application. The application executes various ssh operations over `pexpect` with publickey-authentication. The problem is however, when I start my app with the .desktop launcher it doesn't work properly. The ssh connections ask for a password and don't use the publickeys. But it works fine via commandline execution.

The .desktop File looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=SSH-Manager
Comment=XYZ
Exec=python /home/userx/SSH-Manager/startup.py
Icon=/home/userx/SSH-Manager/resources/icon.png
Path=/home/userx/repos/SSH-Manager
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
StartupNotify=false
```

The desktop environment is KDE and the desktop user is the same as the commandline user.

Can someone explain why I get such strange behavior with the launcher?

Edit: Example function

```
def run(self):
    self.a_signal.emit("Retrieving Data")
    try:
        session = pxssh()
        session.force_password = False
        hostname = self.client
        username = "root"
        session.login(hostname, username)
        session.sendline("ls -a")
        session.prompt()
        session.logout()
    except ExceptionPxssh as e:
        print ("pxssh failed: ")
        self.error_signal.emit("failed", str(e))
        print e
        return
    self.process_output()
    self.finish_signal.emit("done")
```

Comment: Desktop entry looks good. The problem is either in Python program (impossible to tell without code), or in Desktop environment differing from terminal environment. Depending on how you start X, some crucial environment variables might be missing. You will be missing environmental variables also if you are using ssh-agent, but starting it from terminal. ssh-agent should be started before X for all processes to share one agent.

Comment: I think the ssh-agent is the problem then. Is there maybe a way to bypass this? Maybe starting the python app with a bash script or something like this?

Comment: You can start ssh-agent before X. In Debian, you need to have `/usr/bin/ssh-agent` binary available (provided by `openssh-client` on my system, but I think there are multiple providers) and `x11-common` package installed. Then add line `use-ssh-agent` to `/etc/X11/Xsession.options` file and restart X. This will spawn ssh-agent shared between all desktop processes. You need to add your key manually using `ssh-add path/to/key`; check that it was added with `ssh-add -L`. You can also add key automatically to agent on first request by adding line `AddKeysToAgent=yes` in your `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: I tried everything you explained but I just can't get it to work somehow. I even tried a keypair without a passphrase, but as soon as I start my app with the launcher the ssh operation wants a password. I will add some python code in my question. Maybe you have an idea where the problem could be in the python code.

Comment: I just found a solution. It works when I use the `ssh-add` in the `~/.profile` of the the user. Before the keys where registered in `/etc/profile`. X11 settings you described were already set.

Comment: Running `ssh-add` from `~/.profile` seems wrong, but if that works for you, please consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [marking it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/312562), so this question won't appear on list of unresolved queries anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mirosław Zalewski suspected in the comments, the problem was the `ssh-agent` was not running for the desktop-environment because `ssh-add` was initially used in the `/etc/sources`. Executing `ssh-add` in the X-users `~./profile` therefore solves the problem.