# How to create a .desktop file to launch a python script on linux?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, virtualenv

I created a python script ExeMain.py that use virtualenv for dependence. So to launch this script using .desktop I made this command

```
Exec=sh -c 'source ~/PycharmProjects/ProBlog/venv/bin/activate; python ~/PycharmProjects/ProBlog/ExeMain.py;'
```

Which resulted with this error "sh: 1: source: not found" and followed by "ImportError"

Without the source command in .desktop file with all necessary modules installed in direct python environment it works fine (in other Linux machine). As it seams not to be a good practice i tried using venv. And as of the errors i could see than the import error is because source command is not executed.

When i launch the .desktop file it should execute the ExeMain.py file.

Comment: `~` is probably not expanded. Use `$HOME` instead, or fully expand it. Also [Python-Application .desktop-shortcut causing malfunction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43679016/608639)

Comment: ya i tried using the complete path and also $HOME as said,  but same result.

Comment: You can just use the full path to the `python` binary inside the virtual environment instead of activating it.

Comment: something went wrong i couldn't see the file executing even when i had a input statement at the end.

Comment: to be clear with my previous comment ```Exec=sh -c 'source ~/PycharmProjects/ProBlog/venv/bin/activate; python ~/PycharmProjects/ProBlog/ExeMain.py; python '```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard versions of `sh` does not have the `source` command. Perhaps use /bin/bash instead? So it'd be written something along the lines of this:

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'source /home/username/PycharmProjects/ProBlog/venv/bin/activate && /home/username/PycharmProjects/ProBlog/venv/bin/python /home/username/PycharmProjects/ProBlog/ExeMain.py'
```

I also suggest three other changes: 1) the `&&` operator so that it won't try to run python code until the `activate` is finished, 2) replace the `~` tilde with the full path in case the desktop environment doesn't properly expand it, and 3) put in the full path to the venv python so that it doesn't default to the system python. Some of these may not be necessary (depending on the system setup), but it doesn't hurt to be careful.

Comment: Thank you it worked but gave me a message ''Permission denied'' to execute the ExeMain.py as i forgot to add ```chmod u+x /home/username/PycharmProjects/ProBlog/ExeMain.py``` to Exec now it works perfectly well.

Comment: In addition to `sh` not having `source` command: `virtualenv` works only with `bash` or `zsh`, not `sh`.

Comment: `"Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character ''' outside of a quote.` If this error comes, just use **double quotes** instead of single quotes.